# To construct a disjoint family of open sets $O_i$'s such $x_i\in O_i$, where $\{x_i\}$ is a countably infinite set with no limit point.

Tags: real-analysis

If $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ is a countably infinite set with no limit point in a metric space $X$, then how to construct a family $\mathcal O=\{O_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ of open sets such that $x_n\in O_n$ and $O_m\cap O_n=\emptyset$ for all $m\neq n$?

Since the set $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ has no limit point, so for each $n\in\mathbb N$ the infimum $\inf\limits_{m\neq n}d(x_m,x_n)>0$. After that I am stuck.

Comment: As stated this is not possible, because some term can be repeated a finite number of times and the sequence still have no limit point. For instance, consider the sequence (in $\Bbb R$)  $1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$. This sequence has no limit point, but since $x_1=x_2$ there are no $O_1,O_2$ with the desired properties.

Comment: Yes. I have edited my question.

Comment: You are on the right track; define $r_i = inf_{m \neq n} d(x_m, x_n)$, then one might try setting $O_i = B(x_i, r_i)$, but this does not work because $O_i$ might overlap with some other $O_j$. So all you need to do is to decrease the radius of the balls $O_i$ to $r_i / 2$, and then you can prove that for any $i\neq j$, the intersection $O_i \cap O_j = \emptyset$. (You can do so by contradiction, suppose some point $a \in O_i \cap O_j$ and use the triangle equality)

Answer (score 0):

Further on @Charlie comment - to me a limit point would be a unique accumulation point. That is, merge two sequences that converge together with their distinct limits, and you have  a sequence where you cannot get an open set that contains one of the limits and nothing else. If you have duplicate points then that location is an accumulation point. Checking Wolfram and Wikipedia, I see some details about the exact definition of limit point and accumulation point can get in the way. But, I think the following is on the right track,

If there are no accumulation points, then by definition for each $x_i$ there exists an open neighborhood $N_i$ of $x_i$ that contains none of the other points. If this were not so, then every open neighborhood of $x_i$ contains another point, and that is the meaning of an accumulation point.

Now just take half the greatest lower bound on the distance to each point and construct a disk. To be more constructive.